# Service method wraps object in object in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 app. In this app I created a service ValueService with a method get_values. This method I want to return an array of values:

```
def get_values
 [
  'value_1' => 1,
  'value_2' => 2
 ]
end
```

In my controller where I use this service I do something like this:

```
values = ValueService.new().get_values
```

But now, to get my values I have to do:

```
values[0]['value_1']
```

Why this extra wrapper? I would like to access my values simply with:

```
values['value_1']
```

Comment: Wrap it in curly braces?  { value_1: 1, value_2: 2 }  or you can just call the flatten method on it to remove the outer empty level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code

```
[
  'value_1' => 1,
  'value_2' => 2
]
```

returns Array with one hash element in it (`[{"value_1"=>1, "value_2"=>2}]`)

As already suggested in comments, you need to use hash curly braces literal instead to access to your object by key

```
{
  'value_1' => 1,
  'value_2' => 2
}
```